# Python: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable(Think Python 10.3)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I trying to solve *Think Python* exercise 10.3

> Write a function that takes a list of numbers and returns the cumulative sum; that is, a new list where the ith element is the sum of the first `i + 1` elements from the original list. For example, the cumulative sum of `[1, 2, 3]` is `[1, 3, 6]`.

I get a `TypeError` with this code:

```
def culm_sum(num):
    res= []
    a = 0
    for i in num:
        a += i
        res += a
    return res
```

When I call `culm_sum([1, 2, 3])` I get

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Thank you!

Comment: Check out this thread, it has more than one answer to your question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494594/how-to-write-the-fibonacci-sequence-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you are using to append to your list is incorrect:

```
res += a
```

Instead do

```
res.append(a)
```

What's wrong with `res += a`?  Python expects `a` to be iterable and behind the scenes tries to do the equivalent of:

```
for item in a:
    res.append(a)
```

But since `a` is not iterable, so you get a `TypeError`.

*Note*  I initially thought your error was in `for i in num:` because your variable was poorly named.  It sounds like it's a single integer.  Since it is a list of numbers at least make it plural (`nums`) so that readers of your code are not confused.  (The reader you will usually be helping is future you.)

Comment: HI, thank you for your advice and your edit of my post! Didn't see that before! It works now! Also thank you for your advice on the variable name!

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do this is `extend` your list with an `int`, which is not iterable, and hence the error. You need to add the element to the list using the `append` method :

```
res.append(a)
```

Or, do this, the correct way to `extend` :

```
res += [a]
```

Comment: I don't mention `res += [a]` in my answer because it's a bad habit to create temporary objects needlessly when another simple alternative exists.